# Safari: swap alt modifier with cmd

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari

I use Firefox and Chrome as my main navigators, but I use sometimes Safari to test some developments.

On Firefox and Chrome, typing an URL in the address bar and then pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> makes a new tab to be opened.

On Safari, typing an URL in the address bar and then pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> makes the target address saved to a file (which annoys me because it makes an unuseful file in my Download folder).

To open a new tab after typing the address, I have to use the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd>.

I wonder if it is possible to swap cmd and alt key only for Safari (not other apps) and how to do this, or at least make Safari open a new tab when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> in the address bar.

One last thing: I am on Mavericks

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**Karabiner**](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) with a [private.xml](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en) such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <appdef>
    <appname>SAFARI</appname>
    <equal>com.apple.Safari</equal>
  </appdef>
  <item>
    <name>Swap ⌥↩︎ and ⌘↩︎</name>
    <identifier>SwapAltEnterAndCmdEnter</identifier>
    <only>SAFARI</only>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::RETURN, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE,
      KeyCode::RETURN, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L
    </autogen>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::RETURN, VK_OPTION | ModifierFlag::NONE,
      KeyCode::RETURN, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L
    </autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

You can find the manual [here](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html.en) to know how to edit the private.xml file and update your configuration.

You have to check the small checkbox of the newly defined rule to make it work.

Comment: The **KeyRemap4MacBook** expert to the rescue ;)

Comment: Great! I have to add that you can read the manual here to know how to edit the private.xml file: https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/document.html.en. And that you have to check the small checkbox of the new defined rule to make it work.